# I'm trying to copy the active worksheet to the end of the workbook

Tags: vba, excel

All is working well, but I need the values copied, not the formulas. Also the formatting of the worksheet. This is what I have:

```
Dim strName As String, strSht As String
strName = "DMR" & " " & Range("S1").Value
strSht = ActiveSheet.Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = strName
Sheets(strSht).Range("A1:Y89").Copy
Sheets(strName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

This doesn't do what I am trying to accomplish. Some cells in the active worksheet being copied, have formulas in them. I need to copy the values of the formulas, along with the formatting of the sheet. Can anyone help? I'm using Excel 2013. TIA...

Comment: `Sheets(strName).Range("A1:Y89").value=Sheets(strSht).Range("A1:Y89").value`  then perhaps `Paste:=xlPasteFormats`

Answer (score 1):

There is a known peculiarity when pasting Unions of discontiguous cells that you end up pasting Values and Formats. Excel cannot resolve the relational cell addresses of a discontiguous range of formulas so it opts for the values and carries the formats along for the ride.

```
Dim strName As String, strSht As String

strName = "DMR" & " " & Range("S1").Value
strSht = ActiveSheet.Name

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = strName
Sheets(strSht).Range("A1:Y89, Y91").Copy Destination:=Sheets(strName).Range("A1")
```

The above adds (what I beieve to be a blank, unused cell) Y91 to the original copy range to create a discontiguous union of cells. You will end up with the values and formats with no formulas.

Comment: Looks like you provided a better solution. I added 2 lines of code as follows: [code]Sheets(strName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Sheets(strName).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats[/code] First I had to paste the values and then told it to paste the formats. It works but I knew there was a cleaner solution. Thanks for the help

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got an error. No biggie. It's working great the way I coded. Thanks again!